# Get single value from Json response

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

My Json response looks like this:

```
[{"referenceid":"999","firstname":"Firstname","middlename":"Middlename","lastname":"Surname","shortlisted":"0"}]
```

How can I just retrieve the referenceid value? I've searched and searched... tried all sorts of things but I can only return a "undefined".

Thanks

edit:

Forgot my other code:-

```
function populateFormData() {

var mxKey = $.now();

$.get("\\web\\php\\somesite\\phpData.php?mxKey" + mxKey, function(applicationData) {

    console.log("Application Data: " + applicationData);

    var jsonData = JSON.parse(applicationData);

    console.log("Json Parse Data: " + jsonData);

});
```

}

Comment: json_response[0].referenceid

Comment: I don't know if browsers correct this, but URLs use the slash (`/`) as path separator, not backslash.

Comment: Yea, they correct it but I've changed my code to /... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this:

```
var a = [{
  "referenceid": "999",
  "firstname": "Firstname",
  "middlename": "Middlename",
  "lastname": "Surname",
  "shortlisted": "0"
}];

alert(a[0].referenceid);
```

Comment: This still returns a 'undefined'.    var a = applicationData;
console.log(a[0].referenceid);

Comment: @user1399098: And how about `jsonData[0].referenceid`?

Comment: Gah... thats got it, could have sworn I tried that. Thanks so much :)